# Scraping websites with multiple frames/#document using Relenium

Tags: r, selenium, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape a website using Relenium. However I am getting stuck as the website seems to have multiple frame/#document and using getElementbyXpath() does not access the inner frame. I found a relevant link on how to do this using selenium webdriver (http://assertselenium.com/2013/02/22/handling-iframes-using-webdriver/). But I am not able to figure this out using Relenium. The source looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>...</head>
    <frameset rows="80,*" style="border: 1px black;" noresize="noresize">
      <frame name="surftopframe" src="gpt.php?v=timer&amp;user=satoshimines&amp;pretime=1405388100&amp;id=1025&amp;sid=24526TVM0eU16RTFOVE0&amp;sid2=24526&amp;type=ptc&amp;siduid=24526&amp;" scrolling="no" marginheight="2" marginwidth="2" noresize="noresize">
        #document
         <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
         <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
            <head>...</head>
            <body marginwidth="2" marginheight="2">
            <!--
            <div id="banner"><a href="bannerclick.php?id=228" target="_blank"><img src="http://click2dad.net/_static/_css/img/click2dad_en.gif" alt="Banner Advertisement" /></a></div>
            -->
            <div id="timer">...</div>
            <div id="buttons" style="display: block;">...</div>
            <div id="menu">...</div>
```

Any pointers to an example showing if and how Relenium can deal with these cases will be great.

Thanks

Comment: relenium does not handle frames as far as I know.

Comment: Found the solution. While this is not possible in Relenium there's another package- RSelenium. It handled this task easily. Here's the relevant tutorial http://rpubs.com/johndharrison/12843

Comment: Very good I should say at this point that I am the author of RSelenium before this conversation becomes twilight zone like ....

Comment: @jdharrison- You could have given me a hint !!! But I guess learning is better this way :-) Great work with RSelenium and thanks for such an clear tutorial. Its silly how only now I realized matching name in the link I shared. I wonder why this package hasn't been promoted that much. Its going to be my first choice from now on.